# Assetic - add page specific js files

Tags: javascript, symfony, assetic

I have such a a herarchy in my js:

```
/Scripts
-- jQuery.min.js
-- shared.js
-- /Admin
   -- admin-users.js
   -- admin-files.js
-- /User
   -- user.js
```

The website has a controller for all three specific js files.

I would like assetic to load the files correctly.

How can this be done without havint to put all the names by hand in each view?

Comment: I would suggest to write Twig extension, which takes as arguments Controller name, action, route, and basing on any regexp, you should be able to inject into view files which you want.

Comment: I'm looking for something more lile `{{parent()}}` for assetic